# MongoDB with LOTS OF datas?

Tags: mongodb, large-data

I'm a beginner with a non SQL structure like here with MongoDB and I don't find somebody talk about a collection with lots of data, like 1.000.000 entries ? and more ?

I saw a company page on the [official site](http://www.mongodb.com/company). But nothing with large data companies.

I heard about a combo with SQL : Large data are stocked on SQL tables, and only the "cache" are on MongoDB, but it's the only one solution for MongoDB and large data ?

Comment: 1 million entries is not a lot. Any DB could support that.

Comment: and More ? And i talk about lots of search query.. Mongodb store only object, so i'm scared about requests..

Comment: 1m is large now? Since when? Try coming back to us when you reach 3b

Comment: Was an example.. And not the question.. I ask about huge request on large collections.

Comment: It depends, you could have 300b rows but in reality need no cache on SQL, but then you could have 100m rows and require a serious deployment of redis/mongodb/memcache it all depends upon access and queries and analysis of the data. However, MongoDB can easily handle "big data" as can many techs, even SQL if configured and deployed by someone who knows what they are talking about. Using a tech does not immediately declare win. I know of some terrible mongodb deployment that cannot handle 100,000 rows let alone 1m

Comment: What I would do is get a specification together of what queries you require for your application and what processing you will need, and think of what you could need in say 2 years. That will help you get a rough idea of direction

Comment: Thank you, very usefull  :) And search queries on children fields ? and sorting ? Isn't weigh for object structure ?

Comment: If you are doing serious queries from parent to children relying on sorting child records you might find you need to re-engineer, JOINs are really difficult on massive tables

Comment: Okay thank you, you answer the question fully ! (It's hard to explain for me and my bad english)..

Comment: Ah it's ok sorry for us acting this way, sometimes we can get a bit elitist about definitions, anyway glad to have helped

Comment: The [MongoDB performance at scale](http://mongodb.com/scale) page on MongoDB.com includes some different examples of scale: thousands of nodes, hundreds of thousands of operations per second, hundreds of billions of documents, petabytes of data. A key to scaling any infrastructure is understanding how to properly tune it for your workload (and your budget). It's definitely worth asking questions in community forums to get advice from others who hopefully have more experience. Be sure to dig into the documentation on [Indexing Strategies](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/indexes/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We're using MongoDB to power [Where's it Up](http://wheresitup.com), and the [api behind it](http://api.wheresitup.com). We're currently pushing in >3 million documents per day. MongoDB is the only storage engine in use. We were keeping a bunch around for a while, but we're now using [TTL](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) to delete old records.

Things are going super well, just make sure you have all the indexes you need. Querying a million+ records without an index is bad, regardless of your storage engine. Auto-failover has been super helpful.

Something to watch out for is updating records to include more information, it can be pretty expensive if the document grows past pre-allocated space. We ended up changing how we stored data to avoid updates, and create new documents instead.

Comment: Regarding the update problems: You might have run into a padding problem. Depending on the size difference before and after the update, the move of the updated doc within the data file may be forced. The effective padding factor can easily be adjusted. Fire-and-forget upserts should be pretty fast, as long as you have the queried field(s) in an index.

Comment: How exactly do you adjust the padding factor, I haven't seen anything in the API, and the documented suggestion was adding a bunch of 'aaaaaa' to pre-pad, which is sub-optimal. I wrote about our changes here: http://blog.preinheimer.com/index.php?/archives/428-Wheres-it-Up-System-Upgrades..html performance has gone up, asserts have fallen off completely.

Comment: In mongo terminology, padding means that a certain space is preallocated preparing for the case a document increases during an update. Documents are never fragmented, so if a document increases too much, it is moved to a free location of fitting size in the datafile. I assume this is the case and is causing your problems. It might help if you adjust your [record allocation strategy](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/storage/#record-allocation-strategies).

Comment: Just got the time to read the blog post. In your use case, powerof2sizes should be definetly used, as it increases the padding exponentially as opposed to a constant factor. The other solution I see are SSDs to reduce latency. I am not sure wether it is a good idea to create an intermediate document. May be you are better of using something like ServiceMix, storing the requests in a JMS or AMQP queue and using Camel for the processing and subsequent storage in MongoDB. Probably it could be done without messaging, but `direct:` endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB in it's current incarnation is explicitly designed to make it easy to scale out.

As for the numbers: one of my test databases has 10M records and runs easily on my MacBook Air, which is 4 years old now.

So what you can do when your current cluster can not handle the data stored (either because the indices are too big for your RAM or because of processing the queries takes too long): add another node to your MongoDB cluster. Your performance gain should be something between slightly below linear (if your cluster was in perfect condition otherwise) up to several orders of magnitude (when indices didn't fit into RAM and/or IO was pushed to it's limits before and that situation changed after scaling out).

A word of warning: you should have somebody who knows about MongoDB administration in case you want to put you deployment into production. Though MongoDB administration seems to be easy, it is by no means something to be done by a layman. Especially not for production use.